# Tracking changes in SharePoint using last change token

Tags: python, rest, sharepoint, office365

I need to track changes in SharePoint using last_change_token. I used office365-RestAPI, but I have next error all the time: `ClientRequestException: ('-2147024891, System.UnauthorizedAccessException', 'Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))', "403 Client Error: Forbidden for url:`. These are my permissions in Azure:
[image: My permissions in Azure]

This is my structure in SharePoint:
[image]

````
site_url = 'https://***.sharepoint.com/sites/test-site'
credentials = ClientCredential(client_id=os.getenv('CLIENT_ID'), client_secret=os.getenv('CLIENT_SECRET'))
ctx = ClientContext(site_url).with_credentials(credentials)
target_folder_url = "/sites/test-site/Documents"
folder = ctx.web.get_folder_by_server_relative_url(target_folder_url)

ctx.load(folder)
ctx.execute_query()```
````

Comment: would you please provide us with an update on the status of your issue?

Comment: I couldn’t solve my problem and I decided to stop using office-365 and use requests library and delta links to track changes in my folder.